# How to solve a problem when a verb and a noun is the same?

Tags: word-request

One such word these days is : post!

In a natural flow, I told my friend...

> Yes, I'll post a post!

And, we both English language enthusiasts looked at each other rising eyebrows! It triggered me to put a question here.

How do you say that? It is easy when the *post* is something else and NOT text. Say...

> She posted a picture...

It's fine...but when it's plain text, we call it a 'post.' So, what if she posts a post? A plain text?

What are the options?

---

Edit: I just edited the example to sound better for the question.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with "posted a post", though people will often avoid the repetition.

Comment: I edited to sound better. *Posted a post* still has two different words! Posted and 'post.' Future tense will really look like repeating the same thing! @ColinFine

Comment: What about publish?

Comment: You could just leave out the object noun altogether: "Yes, I'll post!"

Answer (score 1):

There's no problem with the given example (*Yes, I'll post a post!*). It's easily understood that the first is a verb and the second is a noun. People may try to avoid repetition for stylistic reasons, but there's nothing ungrammatical about it.

In any case, you can use your best judgement to assess what the text is. If the text is a question, use the word *question*. If it's a comment, message, essay, rant, or whatever, use one of those:

> 1. Yes, I'll post a question!
> 2. Yes, I'll post a comment!
> 3. Yes, I'll post a message!
> 4. etc.